# Error:A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Tags: lambda

```
List<BusinessObjects.BusinessEntity> relatedBEs = 
    (from be in context.BusinessEntities
.Where(w=> RelatedBusinessEntityGuids.Contains(w.BusinessEntityGuid))
.Select(s=>s.Name)).ToList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<BusinessObjects.BusinessEntity> relatedBEs = context.BusinessEntities.Where(w=> RelatedBusinessEntityGuids.Contains(w.BusinessEntityGuid)).ToList();
```

**update:**

```
List<string> names= context.BusinessEntities.Where(w=> RelatedBusinessEntityGuids.Contains(w.BusinessEntityGuid)).Select(s=>s.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: it is good but now i want only the column of table businessentities name "NAME" ?